# Prevent login if username is blank for stored procedure

Tags: sql, sql-server

In a database `userrecord` I have a user with a blank login name, and this user has been able to log in to his account with only password. How can this be prevented? And advise please?

Comment: Apart from the answers provided, I suggest that you alter your table so that username column is not allowed to be null (might be worth making it unique too). You could also add a check constraint so that the username value could not be an empty string.

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
IF NULLIF(@LoginName, '') IS NULL ...
```

Or

```
IF(@LoginName IS NULL OR @LoginName = '') ...
```

Answer (score 0):

Place this in your login SP

```
if len(isnull(@LoginName,'')) = 0 -- or <@MinLoginNameLength if you wish
   Begin
--      Select 'naughty, get a username'
        RAISERROR('%s',16,1,'cheaters never prosper.')
   end
```

Comment: Thanks wheeler and sami.

Answer (score 0):

100% Work

```
if(@LoginName IS NOT NULL OR @LoginName <> '')
{
-- Your Statement or your Query
}
```

Please try this query